# Read input from file and pass it to sub shell

Tags: shell, unix, multiprocess, subshell

i have a scenario where in i have to monitor jobs which run in different servers, The job details(job name, host server, etc) are present in a dat file.

I have written a script a script which reads the details from the dat file and calls a local method where the job monitoring logic is present.

The script is working fine and the job are being monitored sequentially i.e one job at a time.

I want to monitor the jobs concurrently that is pass the job details to subshells so that each of the job is monitored concurrently.

i have added logic for creating subshell (appended & at the end of the method ) for each of the job but the jobs are still being monitored sequentially.

Is ther any other way of calling the local method in sub shell ?

Monitoring script

```
 monitor_job()  {
 # Monitoring logic
 }

while IFS='|' read JOB_NAME DEST_HOST CONCURRENT
do
    if [[ -n "$JOB_NAME" && "$JOB_NAME" != *#* ]]
    then
            monitor_job $JOB_NAME $DEST_HOST $CONCURRENT
    fi
done < "$DAILY_JOBS"
```

Input dat file

```
##########################################################
## List of Daily Jobs that are to be monitored
#
## Job Name | Host Server | Concurrent Process
##########################################################

Job1|host1|&
Job2|host2|&
Job3|host3|&
Job4|host4|&
Job5|host5|&
```

Comment: Mmm what is the question?

Comment: want to call the monitor_job in a subshell so that all the jobs are monitored concurrently.